# How to query all eventMessages from a specific event on Microsoft Graph API

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the eventMessages that belongs to a specific event. However I'm not being able to.

I'm querying the `me/messages` with the `$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event` and trying to filter on this relationship:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event&filter=event/id eq 'eventID'`

However, I'm getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'event' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cb211061-802b-4657-a191-f06c449897d1",
            "date": "2019-05-16T14:01:43"
        }
    }
}
```

But looking at [their example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/eventmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#request-2) of expanding the message with the event, there is an event property on the return of the API (see returned JSON below).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('8fd6e83b-3cc0-4bf0-8b26-950f4d7110f6')/messages/$entity",
   "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
   "@odata.etag":"W/\"CwAAABYAAABXlB/SL0N4Q6g6o+jSYAEuAAAImkVF\"",
   "id":"AAMkADYAAAImV_jAAA=",
   "createdDateTime":"2017-12-27T21:54:55Z",
   "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-12-27T23:26:38Z",
   "changeKey":"CwAAABYAAABXlB/SL0N4Q6g6o+jSYAEuAAAImkVF",
   "categories":[

   ],
   "receivedDateTime":"2017-12-27T21:54:55Z",
   "sentDateTime":"2017-12-27T21:54:54Z",
   "hasAttachments":false,
   "internetMessageId":"<MWHPR1301MB211042CF@MWHPR1301MB2110.namprd13.prod.outlook.com>",
   "subject":"Kick off planning",
   "bodyPreview":"Let's collect opinions from our teams and organize action items.",
   "importance":"normal",
    "parentFolderId":"AQMkADYAS4AAAIBDAAAAA==",
    "conversationId":"AAQkADYRuffB3wDlPn-ReFZarI60=",
   "isDeliveryReceiptRequested":null,
   "isReadReceiptRequested":false,
   "isRead":false,
   "isDraft":false,
   "webLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADYAAAImV%2BjAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
   "inferenceClassification":"focused",
   "meetingMessageType":"meetingRequest",
   "body":{
      "contentType":"html",
      "content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" dir=\"ltr\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p style=\"margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0\">Let's collect opinions from our teams and organize action items.<br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
   },
   "sender":{
      "emailAddress":{
         "name":"Administrator",
         "address":"admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
   },
   "from":{
      "emailAddress":{
         "name":"Administrator",
         "address":"admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
   },
   "toRecipients":[
      {
         "emailAddress":{
            "name":"Alex Wilber",
            "address":"AlexW@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ccRecipients":[

   ],
   "bccRecipients":[

   ],
   "replyTo":[

   ],
   "event@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('8fd6e83b-3cc0-4bf0-8b26-950f4d7110f6')/messages('AAMkADYAAAImV_jAAA%3D')/microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event/$entity",
   "event":{
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"V5Qf0i9DeEOoOqPo0mABLgAACJpBWg==\"",
      "id":"AAMkADYAAAImVu6AAA=",
      "createdDateTime":"2017-12-27T21:54:55.2624551Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-12-27T22:19:16.6667889Z",
      "changeKey":"V5Qf0i9DeEOoOqPo0mABLgAACJpBWg==",
      "categories":[

      ],
      "originalStartTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time",
      "originalEndTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time",
      "iCalUId":"040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A2A6F3535D7FD3010000000000000000100000003D770E2E8974F44B9471BDB348097FE3",
      "reminderMinutesBeforeStart":15,
      "isReminderOn":true,
      "hasAttachments":false,
      "subject":"Kick off planning",
      "bodyPreview":"Let's collect opinions from our teams and organize action items.",
      "importance":"normal",
      "sensitivity":"normal",
      "isAllDay":false,
      "isCancelled":false,
      "isOrganizer":false,
      "responseRequested":true,
      "seriesMasterId":null,
      "showAs":"tentative",
      "type":"singleInstance",
      "webLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADYAAAImVu6AAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
      "onlineMeetingUrl":null,
      "responseStatus":{
         "response":"tentativelyAccepted",
         "time":"2017-12-27T22:19:12.6197462Z"
      },
      "body":{
         "contentType":"html",
         "content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" dir=\"ltr\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p style=\"margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0\">Let's collect opinions from our teams and organize action items.<br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
      },
      "start":{
         "dateTime":"2018-02-02T22:00:00.0000000",
         "timeZone":"UTC"
      },
      "end":{
         "dateTime":"2018-02-02T23:00:00.0000000",
         "timeZone":"UTC"
      },
      "location":{
         "displayName":"Mt. Hood"
      },
      "recurrence":null,
      "attendees":[
         {
            "type":"required",
            "status":{
               "response":"none",
               "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress":{
               "name":"Administrator",
               "address":"admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"required",
            "status":{
               "response":"tentativelyAccepted",
               "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress":{
               "name":"Alex Wilber",
               "address":"AlexW@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
         }
      ],
      "organizer":{
         "emailAddress":{
            "name":"Administrator",
            "address":"admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would expect that the above filter would make the API return only the messages belonging to that event. However, it's giving me a 400 and I think it might be because of the syntax on how to filter in this specific case, but I can't find anything on their documentation about this. Does anybody know how to perform this kind of filter on the graph API?

Comment: Hi Lucas, Were you able to find answer? I am also struggling with same issue